# Google+ login in android and then maintain offline session

Tags: android, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-play-services

**Scope**

I want to have google login in my app. For this I referred to https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in and was able to create a basic login.

**Problem**

Now, the problem is quite interesting. The login process works like a charm, but only when internet is connected. Lets get to a specific use case:

1. I started the app, logged in with my xxxx@gmail.com.
2. I closed the app, started again. It automatically logs in to xxxx@gmail.com. Technically: onConnected() gets called. (It has to be like this, no problem)
3. I closed the app, and turned off the internet connectivity.
4. Now again started the app the account gets logged out as I can see in logs: 'clearing selected account for *packagename' - (something related to this)
5. I again switched on the internet connectivity and then started the app, nothing happens. It(the account) doesnt gets logged in (since it was logged out automatically).
   Technically: this time onConnectionFailed() gets called

So, I want to keep this login even if the internet is switched off, what can I do?
A couple of other apps do this stuff.

**Self Digging**

1. I went through the logs of other popular apps having google Login, and in which the login persists even if the internet is not connected and compared those logs with that of my apps' logs.

Logs in Other apps:

```
  02-16 00:51:13.493: W/GLSUser(26959): [GLSUser] [GLSUser]  Permission for *packagename* to access oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email will be managed locally.
```

Logs in My apps:

```
   02-16 00:50:16.203: W/GLSUser(26959): [GLSUser] [GLSUser]  Permission for *packagename* to access oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me will be managed remotely.
```

2. I found that this weird thing happens only when I am using scope =

   ```
   Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE
   ```

   However, when I use scope = 'email' or 'profile' or Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN. It works fine in offline mode.

Can anybody help me ??

Comment: Did you follow the "Enable server-side API access for your app" section in https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in ? It talks about offline access as opposed to regular access which you are having.

Comment: No Kiran, I would be going through it by today. Thankyou.

Comment: One thing: under "Enable server-side API access for your app" its written "With the earlier Add sign-in button procedure, your app uses GoogleApiClient.connect() to authenticate the user on the client side only; in that case, GoogleApiClient is able to access the Google APIs only while the user is actively using your app".  ---> does this mean that this time I should not use GoogleApiClient.connect() ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are not storing the credentials (the Auth Token) and using it to re-authenticate on resume.

Check [this](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/calendar-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar) sample from the Google API client for java.

Comment: Though this answer may be helpful for the OP, I suggest you include a bit more information. External links can break over time, and affect the usability of this answer in future.

Comment: For your clarification : if we are using Google+ sign in. All this stuff is handled by the API itself. We do not actually have to store the credentials if we are only having login on "installed application". I may be wrong though.